# Restructuring pandas dataframe based on repeating sections

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `.csv` file that I wish to convert to a dataframe, and restructure that dataframe such that it follows a specific format.

The format of the `.csv` file is such that data appears in the same format in each 'section', which occurs after a certain amount of rows (can change depending on the file) but always starts at the `SECTION` cell. Here is an excerpt showing just two sections.

```
LOT 1           
DESCRIPTION red         
MEAN    0.5         
MIN 0.1         
MAX 0.85            
Iteration # Value   Value   A   B
1   500 10  20  30
2   510 10  2   3
3   488 10  2   3
                
SECTION     1           
LOT 2           
DESCRIPTION blue            
MEAN    0.6         
MIN 0.1         
MAX 1.1         
Iteration # Value   Value   A   B
1   500 10  15  20
2   550 10  2   3
3   450 10  2   3
```

I can read in the whole dataframe just fine with `pd.read_csv()`. However, I would like to restructure the dataframe so that it resembles the following format:

[image: desired dataframe structure]

How can I do this such that it acts for all n sections present in the `.csv` file?, and ends with n columns of data as shown?

Comment: can you add a sample of your data as text to the question (not as image)? and what about the other parts with the tables of Iteration# and so on. Not needed here at all ?

Comment: The other data is not needed, although if there's a way to organize that separately it would be a nice bonus. Not needed for this though.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way to do this but for now you can try this:

```
with open('your_csv_file.csv') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';') # change to the delimiter you have

    df_dict = {}
    for row in csvreader:
        row = list(filter(None, row))
        if len(row)==2:
            key, value = row
            df_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(df_dict)
# {'SECTION': ['1', '1'], 'LOT': ['1', '2'], 'DESCRIPTION': ['red', 'blue'], 'MEAN': ['0.5', '0.6'], 'MIN': ['0.1', '0.1'], 'MAX': ['0.85', '1.1']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict, 'index')
print(df)

                0     1
SECTION         1     1
LOT             1     2
DESCRIPTION   red  blue
MEAN          0.5   0.6
MIN           0.1   0.1
MAX          0.85   1.1
```

Doing it like this there must be always all values from 'SECTION' to 'MAX' otherwise you get an error. Maybe I find a more dynamic solution.